# How to Click a Button by Name in Browser Console

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I am trying to click a button on a web page using the developer tools console in Google Chrome.

The HTML for the button is:

```
<input value="Send an Email" class="btn" name="email" onclick="navigateToUrl('/_ui/core/email/author/EmailAuthor?p2_lkid=00QU0000008xZYi&amp;rtype=00Q&amp;retURL=%2F00QU0000008xZYi','RELATED_LIST','email');" title="Send an Email" type="button">
```

As you can see, the button does not have an `id` attribute, so I'm trying to select it using the `name` attribute. My JavaScript code is:

```
document.getElementsByName("email").click()
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: getElement **s** ByName returns a whole collection, not a single element.

Comment: Look at the name - `getElementsByName`...it's plural "Elements". You can't call `click` on a collection. You need to get a specific item in the collection, probably `[0]`, and call `click` on that one

Comment: In addition to the answers provided, if you have multiple elements with the name "email", instead of just getting the first one (`[0]`), you can loop over the result of `document.getElementsByName("email")` and see if the `value` property is "Send an Email" (here), and only then call `click`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`document.getElementsByName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByName) returns an array (technically a [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList)), so you have to specify the element you want like:

```
document.getElementsByName("email")[0].click()
```

Answer (score 2):

It's been well answered that the issue relies on the fact that `document.getElementsByName()` returns a node list, not a single element.

Just to point an alternative, *no list return* method:

If you want to browse for a single element, and do not have an id, but needs to look for any attribute (not just name), you could call it using `document.querySelector()`, that uses a css-like selector, and returns the first matched element, so:

```
var element = document.querySelector("[name='email']");
```

Comment: For the downvoter: This answer was not posted as to be the accepted one, but since the title of the question is *How to Click a Button by Name in Browser Console*, and the heart of the issue on the description is *the button does not have an id attribute, so I'm trying to select it using the name attribute*, it may attract more people seeking for select an element by attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Elements = plural = node List

You need to select the first one.

```
document.getElementsByName("email")[0].click()
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this to help me with an ajax function call, using the delete button. I wanted to delete an individual numbered record from the database.

```
$(document).on('click', "[name='delete_button']", function(){
   ajax_function();
});
```